# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - Bing Search API

Tags: php, api, search, bing

This is the php code:

```
<?php

$acctKey = 'key';

$rootUri = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search';

$contents = file_get_contents('bing_basic.html');

if ($_POST['query'])
{

$query = urlencode("'{$_POST['query']}'");

$serviceOp = $_POST['service_op'];

$requestUri = "$rootUri/$serviceOp?\$format=json&Query=$query";

$auth = base64_encode("$acctKey:$acctKey");

$data = array('http' => array('request_fulluri' => true,'ignore_errors' => true,'header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth"));

$context = stream_context_create($data);

$response = file_get_contents($requestUri, 0, $context);

$jsonObj = json_decode($response);
$resultStr = '';
foreach($jsonObj->d->results as $value)
{
    switch ($value->__metadata->type)
    {
        case 'WebResult':
        $resultStr .= "<a href=\"{$value->Url}\">{$value->Title}</a><p>{$value->Description}</p>";
        break;
        case 'ImageResult': $resultStr .= "<h4>{$value->Title} ({$value->Width}x{$value->Height}) " . "{$value->FileSize} bytes)</h4>" . "<a href=\"{$value->MediaUrl}\">" . "<img src=\"{$value->Thumbnail->MediaUrl}\"></a><br />";
        break;
    }
}

$contents = str_replace('{RESULTS}', $resultStr, $contents);

}

echo $contents;

?>
```

And tis is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Bing Search Tester (Basic)</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bing Search Tester (Basic)</h1>
<form method="POST" action="bing_basic.php">
<label for="service_op">Service Operation</label><br/>
<input name="service_op" type="radio" value="Web" CHECKED /> Web
<input name="service_op" type="radio" value="Image" /> Image <br/>
<label for="query">Query</label><br/>
<input name="query" type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" value="" /><br /><br />
<input name="bt_search" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form> <h2>Results</h2>
{RESULTS} 
</body>
</html>
```

Why do I keep getting that error ?
This is a duplicate by the way, but the other questions didn't have all the code and there were no answers to my question.

Also, I'm not very familiar with php objects and json..

Api documentation: https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!112&app=Word&authkey=!ANNnJQREB0kDC04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check to ensure that $jsonObj->d->results is indeed an array or that its not empty.

```
if( ( is_array( $jsonObj->d->results ) && ( ! empty( $jsonObj->d->results ) ) {
    foreach($jsonObj->d->results as $value)
    {
        switch ($value->__metadata->type)
        {
            case 'WebResult':
            $resultStr .= "<a href=\"{$value->Url}\">{$value->Title}</a><p>{$value->Description}</p>";
            break;
            case 'ImageResult': $resultStr .= "<h4>{$value->Title} ({$value->Width}x{$value->Height}) " . "{$value->FileSize} bytes)</h4>" . "<a href=\"{$value->MediaUrl}\">" . "<img src=\"{$value->Thumbnail->MediaUrl}\"></a><br />";
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    if( ! is_array( $jsonObj->d->results ) {
        echo "jsonObj->d->results is not an array!";
    } elseif( empty( $jsonObj->d->results ) {
        echo "jsonObj->d->results is empty!";
    }
}
```

Comment: try echo "<pre>".print_r($jsonObj->d->results,true)."</pre>"; to see the contents of the array to ensure it contains what it should contain.

Comment: your code was wrong.. now I see no erros but .. I get no results

Comment: Then the array is empty or it isnt an array - which is the reason why the foreach is returning errors. 

There are no errors because the if statement doesnt satisfy so it skips the foreach altogether. 

Try removing one of the if conditions - the ! empty part or the is_array part to find out which one of those is the real issue.

Comment: jsonObj->d->results is not an array!

Comment: Backtrack through the code where the array should be populating to begin with to see if it either isn't being populated properly or if something else is amiss. The error probably lies therein; however, that is another question entirely and would require much more source code than what is provided. Be sure to mark the answer as accepted if this resolved the original question.